# Does calling email task involve using cryptography or encryption?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I am just calling windows phone compose email task, to let the user request support by email through my app. 
Now, I need to be sure to answer the following question for the windows store :

Does this app call, support, contain, or use cryptography or encryption?

Comment: I'd say no, alrhough it might when the config points to a secured SMTP server. But SSL should be outside the scope of this question, so unless you are deliberately adding encrypted attachments: No